# Storing text with line break in javascript array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form where user can enter a note via a textfield.

When entering the note, user can press 'enter' to add line breaks and also the note entered can consist of multiple lines and it is stored in a table column of type `varchar(2000) latin1_swedish_ci`

On some other page, I am retrieving the notes from the database and storing them in an array. I am alerting the array contents to test whether everything is ok

My problem is that if the note spans on more than 1 line or contains line breaks, it does not seem to be stored in that array and the alert function does not alert anything for that particular note.

However, it is displayed properly if i display it using plain ruby code.

Here is an example of my code:

```
/********** loop through the resultset and store the values in the test_array **********/
<% @saved_note.each do |note| %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        testarray[note_counter] = '<%= note.value %>';
        alert(testarray[note_counter]);
        note_counter++;
    </script>
    <%= note.value %> 
<% end %>
```

Any suggestion is most appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If `note.value` spans more than one line, you will have this result:

```
testarray[note_counter] = 'Dear tanya,
how are you doing today?
sincerely, 
user';
```

The problem here is that javascript doesn't support multiline strings without [some massaging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/multiline-strings-in-javascript). If you've got any kind of newline characters hanging out in `note.value`, you'll want to escape them (see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653040/inserting-escape-characters)) before printing them out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
testarray[note_counter] = <%= raw note.value.to_json %>;
```

Personnaly I store that in `AplicationHelper`

```
def json value
  raw value.to_json
end
```

and then in your view

```
testarray[note_counter] = <%= json note.value %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to find an exact example of how I dealt with that in php, but the idea would be to try to parse all the symbols to their ansi code and check for the needed symbol like that. Just an idea tho.